# Search for keys in nested object and delete them

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I need to remove certain keys from an object provide those keys are included in my 'deleteKeys' array.

How could I achieve this in optimized manner?

Here's the code:

```js
const data = {
  "details": [{
    "userId": "user01",
    "documents": [{
      "document": {
        "id": "doc_pp_01",
        "type": "pp",
        "number": "222333444",
        "personName": {
          "first": "JAMES",
          "middle": "JOHNIE",
          "last": "SMITH"
        },
        "nationality": "AL",
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
        "issuingCountry": "AL",
        "expiryDate": "2025-01-01",
        "gender": "MALE"
      }
    }]
  }],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    "fullName": "James Johnie Smith"
  }
};
const deleteKeys = ["details", "fullName"];

function cleanData(data) {
  for (let elem in data) {
    if (deleteKeys.includes(elem)) {
      delete data[elem];
    }
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(cleanData(data));
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234"
  }
};
```

I was wondering if I could achieve this by stringifying the object as it would be a cleaner solution.

```
function assignKey(data) {
  const formattedData = JSON.stringify(data);
  deleteKeys.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (formattedData.includes(elem)) {
      formattedData.replace(elem, '');
    }
  });
  return JSON.parse(formattedData);
}
```

Comment: Stringifying it is not cleaner, on the contrary. The only problem with your code is that it only considers the top level. Try calling `cleanData(data[elem]);` in your for loop to make it recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your function recursive with only a few changes. I changed `deleteKeys` into a parameter, which I find cleaner, but is not essential.

```js
function cleanData(data, deleteKeys) {
  // There is nothing to be done if `data` is not an object,
  // but for example "user01" or "MALE".
  if (typeof data != "object") return;
  if (!data) return; // null object
  
  for (const key in data) {
    if (deleteKeys.includes(key)) {
      delete data[key];
    } else {
      // If the key is not deleted from the current `data` object,
      // the value should be check for black-listed keys.
      cleanData(data[key], deleteKeys);
    }
  }
}

const data = {
  "details": [{
    "userId": "user01",
    "documents": [{
      "document": {
        "id": "doc_pp_01",
        "type": "pp",
        "number": "222333444",
        "personName": {
          "first": "JAMES",
          "middle": "JOHNIE",
          "last": "SMITH"
        },
        "nationality": "AL",
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
        "issuingCountry": "AL",
        "expiryDate": "2025-01-01",
        "gender": "MALE"
      }
    }]
  }],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    "fullName": "James Johnie Smith"
  }
};

cleanData(data, ["details", "fullName"]);
console.log(data);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that `delete` mutates the existing object. This means that returning `data` is not essential.

Functions like `reverse()` and `sort()` do return the array, even though they mutate the existing array. This often leads to bugs/issues with novice JavaScript programmers.

```
const foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
const bar = foo.reverse();
```

The above code suggests that `foo` and `bar` are two different arrays. This is not the case. They both refer to the same array, thus `foo` and `bar` are now both reversed. For this reason I often don't use the return value of mutating code on Stack Overflow. The following example much better displays that the code is mutating.

```
const foo = ["a", "b", "c"];
foo.reverse();
```

This is the reason I would personally **not** return from `cleanData()`. This forces users to notice that your function is mutating.

There is also something to be said for returning the input, since you can then chain the return value with other methods/functions. But my personal take is that the disadvantage of misunderstanding outweighs the advantage of chaining. Especially on a "learning" platform like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with using `delete` is that you are essentially altering the original object. This can cause problems if you are using the same Object reference in different locations.

The JSON method will not work, since the resulting JSON string is not valid after removing parts of the string. You could make this work but is much more prone to errors.

I always like to make this kind of function return a new instance of the Object.

```
function removeKeys(obj, keys) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map(item => removeKeys(item, keys));

  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((previousValue, key) => {
      return keys.includes(key) ? previousValue : { ...previousValue, [key]: removeKeys(obj[key], keys) };
    }, {});
  }

  return obj;
}
```

It is also possible to first shallow copy the Object and use `delete` on the new Object instead of using `reduce`.

```js
function removeKeys(obj, keys) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map((item) => removeKeys(item, keys));

  if (typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((previousValue, key) => {
      return keys.includes(key)
        ? previousValue
        : { ...previousValue, [key]: removeKeys(obj[key], keys) };
    }, {});
  }

  return obj;
}

const data = {
  details: [
    {
      userId: "user01",
      documents: [
        {
          document: {
            id: "doc_pp_01",
            type: "pp",
            number: "222333444",
            personName: {
              first: "JAMES",
              middle: "JOHNIE",
              last: "SMITH"
            },
            nationality: "AL",
            dateOfBirth: "1990-01-01",
            issuingCountry: "AL",
            expiryDate: "2025-01-01",
            gender: "MALE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  criteria: {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    fullName: "James Johnie Smith"
  }
};

console.log(
  "Without `fullName` and `details`",
  removeKeys(data, ["fullName", "details"])
);
console.log("Without `id:` and `gender`", removeKeys(data, ["id:", "gender"]));
```

Comment: I want to remove a key that is in the middle of an object, e.g. given `{a:{b:{c}}}` and want to remove b so that `{a:{c}}` remains. Is it possible with your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the empty arrays or objects after deleting keys, the following implementation will work.

```
function cleanData(data, deletingKeys) {
  function isEmpty(obj) {
    if (obj === null) return true;
    if (Array.isArray(obj))
      return obj.length === 0;
    if (typeof obj === "object")
      return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
  }

  function removeKeyFrom(aData) {
    if (Array.isArray(aData)) {
      const done = aData.reduce((accum, ele) => {
        const done = removeKeyFrom(ele);
        if (!isEmpty(done))
          accum.push(done);
        return accum;
      }, []);
      return done.length > 0 ? done : null;
    }
    if (typeof aData === "object" && aData !== null) {
      const done = Object.keys(aData).reduce((accum, key) => {
        if (!deletingKeys.includes(key)) {
          const done = removeKeyFrom(aData[key]);
          if (!isEmpty(done)) // required for empty object element
            accum[key] = done;
        }
        return accum;
      }, {});
      return (Object.keys(done).length > 0) ? done : null;
    }
    return aData;
  }
  return removeKeyFrom(data);
}
```

Suppose that your data and the deleting criteria are as following:

```
const data = {
  "details2": [{
    "userId": "user01",
    // `documents` should be removed since the value is the array of an empty object
    "documents": [{
      "details": { // this should be removed
        "id": "doc_pp_01",
        "type": "pp",
        "number": "222333444",
        "personName": {
          "first": "JAMES",
          "middle": "JOHNIE",
          "last": "SMITH"
        },
        "nationality": "AL",
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
        "issuingCountry": "AL",
        "expiryDate": "2025-01-01",
        "gender": "MALE"
      }
    }]
  }],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    "fullName": "James Johnie Smith",
    "shouldBeRemoved": { // this should be removed since the value will be the empty object
      "details": {
        "whatever": 1234
      }
    }
  }
};

const deleteKeys = ["details", "fullName"];
```

Calling `cleanData(data, deleteKeys)` will result in

```
{
  "details2": [
    {
      "userId": "user01"
    }
  ],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234"
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "details2": [
    {
      "userId": "user01",
      "documents": [
        {}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    "shouldBeRemoved": {}
  }
}
```

Here is the complete code to run.

```js
function cleanData(data, deletingKeys) {
  function isEmpty(obj) {
    if (obj === null) return true;
    if (Array.isArray(obj))
      return obj.length === 0;
    if (typeof obj === "object")
      return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
  }

  function removeKeyFrom(aData) {
    if (Array.isArray(aData)) {
      const done = aData.reduce((accum, ele) => {
        const done = removeKeyFrom(ele);
        if (!isEmpty(done))
          accum.push(done);
        return accum;
      }, []);
      return done.length > 0 ? done : null;
    }
    if (typeof aData === "object" && aData !== null) {
      const done = Object.keys(aData).reduce((accum, key) => {
        if (!deletingKeys.includes(key)) {
          const done = removeKeyFrom(aData[key]);
          if (!isEmpty(done)) // required for empty object element
            accum[key] = done;
        }
        return accum;
      }, {});
      return (Object.keys(done).length > 0) ? done : null;
    }
    return aData;
  }
  return removeKeyFrom(data);
}

const data = {
  "details2": [{
    "userId": "user01",
    // `documents` should be removed since the value is the array of empty object
    "documents": [{
      "details": { // this should be removed
        "id": "doc_pp_01",
        "type": "pp",
        "number": "222333444",
        "personName": {
          "first": "JAMES",
          "middle": "JOHNIE",
          "last": "SMITH"
        },
        "nationality": "AL",
        "dateOfBirth": "1990-01-01",
        "issuingCountry": "AL",
        "expiryDate": "2025-01-01",
        "gender": "MALE"
      }
    }]
  }],
  "criteria": {
    "id:": "AB1234",
    "fullName": "James Johnie Smith",
    "shouldBeRemoved": { // this should be removed since the value is the empty object.
      "details": {
        "whatever": 1234
      }
    }
  }
};

const deleteKeys = ["details", "fullName"];

const print = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);

console.log(print(cleanData(data, deleteKeys)));
```